# Highlight Image on Checked

Tags: html, css

HTML

```
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check" class="check-with-label" />
  <label for="check" class="label-for-check">My Label</label>
   <img class="product-add-image-preview" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/417MwhxcFKL._SY300_.jpg" />
<div>
```

CSS

```
.chk:checked + .product-add-image-preview{
    border: 8px solid;
    border-color: #16bb65;
    margin: 2px;
}
```

How do i make the image "highlight" when checked? I can do it for label(bold) but not image.

http://jsfiddle.net/CjpmP/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [**general sibling combinator**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators) `~`:

```
.check-with-label:checked ~ .product-add-image-preview {
  /* style */
}
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/4QV3s/)

The [**adjacent sibling combinator**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators) `+` only selects the immediate succeeding element.